# Extruding from bespoke flat shapes

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to figure out how to create these bespoke interlocking pillow-like shapes. I posted a similar question earlier but think this is a better example of what I'm aiming for. These shapes are bespoke, but have a light sort of pillow shape. Any ideas?

I'm trying allsorts but not getting the consistency of these.

[image]

Comment: So on further digging I've discovered that these were likely created in Adobe Illustrator using the new 3D tools. I would still be interested to see if these are possible in Blender though